# How can I distinguish bewteen application version numbers and IPv4 addresses in the same file?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Working with python 2.7.10, I have found various reg ex strings in Stackoverflow that do a great job of parsing through a log file, and extracting 4 octet values.

Sample:

```
r"((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})"
```

However, the challenge I am facing is how can I use reg ex to differentiate between a product version/build number, and an IP address, keeping in mind that I have no way of validating the IP address across a network.

A sample of a regdump file would include this:

```
 "flash": {
     "installed": true,
     "name": "flash",
     "supportfile": "flash.all.xml",
     "supportversion": "0",
     "version": "18.0.0.209"
  },

 "quicktime": {
     "installed": true,
     "name": "quicktime",
     "supportfile": "quicktime.all.xml",
     "supportversion": "0",
     "version": "7.77.80.95"

\Browser.IntranetSites\2 [REG_SZ] "10.0.0.0/8"
\Browser.IntranetSites\0 [REG_SZ] "127.0.0.0/8"
```

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: Please add examples on what you want the regex to match and what it should not match.

Comment: I am sure there must be some context that will help. Please post the sample input data that you run the regex against.

Comment: How do you found `4.4.4.4` is a version or is an IP?

Comment: How would *you* (as a person) tell them apart?

Comment: If you're lucky, the version numbers of software can be identified by the environment, like in python-2.7.2.2 (if it exists, don't know ;). IP addresses might be surrounded by blank space or some sort of brackets. But for the rest, the version 2.7.2.2 is indistinguishable from the IP address 2.7.2.2.

Comment: @ScottHunter IP addresses are easy, depending on where they are in the assorted files. Version numbers, not so much, mainly because they are not always led by "version=..." Sometimes it could be Ver, build, B, V, or even just the product name.

Comment: @Binwooke if IP addresses are easy (they follow a very defined set of rules for where they appear), a version could just be a number that matches the pattern but isn't an IP:  (pseudocode) `if ($num =~ /$ipregex/ && other rules here)` `else if ($num =~ /$verregex/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IPs are always followed by the class (e.g. `/8`) you can use that to distinguish the two:

```
(?<=\")(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(?=\")
```

The previous matches the versions while the following matches the IP addresses:

```
(?<=\")(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(?=\/\d+\")
```

If you remove that assumption, there is no way to distinguish between the two since any IP address can also be a version number.

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunately not all IP addresses I need to find have a class suffix.